# $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\|\nabla f(x^k)\right\|_2^2<\infty\Rightarrow\lim_{k\to\infty}\nabla f(x^k)=0$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, convergence-divergence

Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $(x^k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ with $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\|\nabla f(x^k)\right\|_2^2<\infty$$ Why can we conclude that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\nabla f(x^k)=0\;?$$

Comment: If $\sum_n a_n$ converges, then $a_n$ tends to zero, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\|\nabla f(x^k)\right\|_2^2<\infty$, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is an integer $N\geq 0$ such that
$$\left\|\nabla f(x^k)\right\|_2^2<\varepsilon\quad\quad\forall k\geq N$$
*i.e.* $\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty} \left\|\nabla f(x^k)\right\|_2^2=0$. Thus $\nabla f(x^k)$ tends to zero when $k$ tends to infinity a.e.

Now $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ hence $\nabla f(x^k)$ is continuous hence $\nabla f(x^k)$ tends to zero when $k$ tends to infinity everywhere.

Comment: Comment : I treated $\nabla f(x^k)$ as a function, with $x^k$ a function of the coordinates of the vector $x$, and thus $\|.\|_2$ the $L^2$ norm. But after re-reading the question, I am not sure I had really understood it. If $\|.\|_2$ was the euclidian norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the first part of my answer still holds, but not the end (almost everywhere has no sense without $L^p$ norm).